# How to plot using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, plot

I have a data set like this

[Data set](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oZCba.png)

And I want to plot flux/date for each target in each passband
[Something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7M7Pq.png)

I have tried  it using `pandas` but I have no idea how to do it. I have tried `plot.bar` and `plot.hist`

Greetings and thanks in advance

Edit: I'm using Modified Julian Date instead of Calendar date

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`pivot_table`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) with [`DataFrame.plot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html), if necessary change aggregate function to `sum`, `mean` ...:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['2022-01-01','2022-01-10','2023-01-01', '2023-02-10'],
                   'passband':[1,1,2,2],
                   'flux':[2,8,5,6]})
print (df)
         date  passband  flux
0  2022-01-01         1     2
1  2022-01-10         1     8
2  2023-01-01         2     5
3  2023-02-10         2     6

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])

df['year'] = df['date'].dt.year
df1 = df.pivot_table(index='year',
                     columns='passband',
                     values='flux',
                     aggfunc='sum',
                     fill_value=0)
print (df1)
passband   1   2
year            
2022      10   0
2023       0  11

df1.plot()
```

Comment: It gives me the next error:
 'ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape'

Comment: @A.Esquivias - Sorry, answer was changed to `pivot_table`

Comment: Should I use the whole data frame as `data`

`TypeError: pivot_table() missing 1 required positional argument: 'data'`

Comment: @A.Esquivias - You are right, added solution with new helper column and sample data.

Comment: It worked out (no errors) but didn't plot it, just created a table instead of a graph

Comment: @A.Esquivias - super, last add `df1.plot()`